# How to create a scalable Angular application structure?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm creating an **Angular 6** application that will serve two types of users. 
A buyer and a seller. I want each one of them to have their own GUI. How would you structure your application? taking into account that both theses GUIs have many components that they can share. 
I was thinking something like creating 3 modules /buyer , /seller and /shared
I will also be using an auth guard so when authenticating the buyer can only access their GUI , etc ...

I'm new to Angular so any help will be appreciated! 
thank you.

Comment: https://blog.nrwl.io/announcing-nrwl-nx-6-0-29b963d87d8e could help

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a buyer module containing all the components for the buyer,
a seller module containing all the components for the seller
and a shared module containing all components/services/models used in both buyer & seller module.

This is only the first layer, depending on how big your application is you will need more levels of modules.

The offcial Angular styleguide is a good point to start, you can find it [here](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide).
For more about application structure you can look [here](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#lift) in the styleguide.

Answer (score 0):

Create 3 separate module with main module and put common things in main module or **create one shared module** and import where you want to access.
also use `SCSS` for styling and create one separate folder for `sass` and write all the basic files and things in `scss`
You can also create separate folder in asstes for mock-data

Your project structure would be something like that:

```
app/
   core/
   shared/
assets/
    mock-data/
    sass/
```